# Update option in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating admin theme option in WordPress, Everything works perfectly except one function "Updating option"  when I make changes through options admin panel and save changes, I get message "options settings saved." but when I check my page I see nothing is changed.

Here is my code for updating or save option:

```
 function mytheme_add_admin() {

    global $themename, $shortname, $options;

    if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {

        if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

            foreach ($options as $value) {
                update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); 
            }

            foreach ($options as $value) {
                if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) 
                { 
                    update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); 
                } 
                else {
                    delete_option( $value['id'] ); 
                } 
            }

            header("Location: admin.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
            die;

        } 
        else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

            foreach ($options as $value) {
                delete_option( $value['id'] ); 
            }

            header("Location: admin.php?page=functions.php&reset=true");
            die;

        }
    }

    add_menu_page($themename, $themename, 'administrator', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');
}

function mytheme_add_init() {

}
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you check in table?

Comment: What do you mean? can you please explain.?

Comment: You were saying that nothing is changed so I was asking that value is stored in the table or not?

Comment: Yes Values are stored in the table

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the else statement that will retrieve and show the option values.

Here is some explanation :

Your code about the request action is only state with save and reset actions, you miss a normal behaviour to display the options values.

A little example :

```
if('save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ){
    // use update_option
}
elseif( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ){
   // use delete_option
}
else{
  // use get_option
}
```

The global $option you ask at the top of the function is related to a name that you need to be unique, i.e : `my_theme_options['ID']`, when you retrieve option, save option, you need to specify it. 
For example :

```
 $options = get_option('my_theme_option');
```

Then to display your option value, you get it with `$options['ID'];`

So to display an input box, you will need something like this :

```
echo '<input name="my_theme_options[ID]" value="'.$options['ID'].'" type="text"/>';
```

You need to adapt this in your foreach loop with any input or select form tag.

Hope you understand what I mean !

Comment: Can you please explain?